# Trying to setup Auth0 with my Cordova Vue js project

Tags: vue.js, cordova, auth0

So I created the entire website using auth0. But then when I compiled the web app using Cordova, auth0 is giving me errors relating to callback URLs. Auth0 provides a Quickstart guide to config with Cordova, but it relies on Cordova plugins which I cannot seem to access.
It seems like a small error, just the callback URL is wrong. But no matter what I do I cannot seem to make it work.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thank you!